# Binding a save command WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

I have a window with 3 textboxes in a grid -this is my view- and I have Save button to add a new user to my user list with the datas from the textboxes. 
I want to use a relay command to do this on my viewmodel class but I am quite confused with how to make the bindings. I hope it's clear enough. Any ideas, or examples will be helpful.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a ViewModel something like the following :

```
class UserViewModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand AddUserCommand { get; set; }

    public UserViewModel()
    {
        AddUserCommand = new RelayCommand(AddUser);
    }

    void AddUser(object parameter)
    { 
        // Code to add user here.
    }
}
```

And you can use it like following :

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Password}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Email}"></TextBox>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddUserCommand}">Add</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

To make this work, put following code in your UserControl/Control/Window's constructor :

```
DataContext = new UserViewModel();
```

Comment: Are those codes enough to supply the relationship between view and viewmodel? it still doesn't work...

Comment: You have to create an object of the ViewModel and to assign it to the DataContext of the window

Comment: yes, assigning the datacontext was the lack of my code. thanks=)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you read Josh Smith article: [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). If you didn't, then read it first, and then download code, because example is very similar to your problem.

Comment: I understand you :). Been there. I got parts of it after third reading and studying code. Needs time to catch what's happening. At least I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created an instance of the ViewModel and putted this instance in the DataContext of your view or stackpanel?

example:

```
UserViewModel viewModel = new UserViewModel();
UserWindow view = new UserWindow();
view.DataContext = viewModel;
view.Show();
```

There are several options on coupling the View and the Viewmodel:

- Create the View and ViewModel and set the ViewModel to the DataContext property (code above)
- Create the ViewModel in the constructor of the View and fill the DataContext property with it
- Create a Resource in your view of the type of your ViewModel and fill the DataContext property in XAML

I prefer the first option because you can combine the Views and Viewmodels as you like at runtime.

Hopefully this is a helpfull answer.